# Excel become really slow because of a lot of xlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlookup

Hi any remedy to make my excel faster?

This is some sample of my excel formulas

Please help me this is the first time I experience this issue don't know what to do.

Thank you

Comment: xlookup =b5&c2,NAME&DATE,LEAVE,"")
xlookup = b6&c2,NAME&DATE,LEAVE,"")
xlookup =b7&c2,NAME&DATE, LEAVE,"")
xlookup =b8&c2,NAME&DATE, LEAVE,"")
Then drag the formula until
=xlookup =b55&c2,NAME&DATE,LEAVE,"")
And also I would need to drag the formula from
xlookup =b5&c2,NAME&DATE,LEAVE,"")
xlookup =b55&c2,NAME&DATE,LEAVE,"")
xlookup =b5&AG2,NAME&DATE,LEAVE,"")
xlookup =b55&AG2,NAME&DATE, LEAVE,"")

Comment: So complete the xlookups, then paste special values and work with the results. Update and repeat as needed.

Comment: @SolarMike can you give an example gor that sir?. Actually my excel file now is still loading until now. Haha

Comment: How large are these ranges `NAME` and `DATE`? Possibly rework how you define these.

Comment: Select the cells, in the Edit menu: copy then paste.special values.

Comment: @jvdv. For NAME AND DATE. Actually more like 500 rows.

Comment: Then it's hard to believe that `XLOOKUP()` is the issue to your extremely slow workbook.

Comment: @jvdv now what i did is i seperate my xlookup file from the vba file. Now the loading time is 1-2mins. Is there some ways to make it more faster?

Comment: Not without knowing what code you are using